# How to make Google Play Games Services work with a published OAuth consent screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-api, google-play-games

I am working on a Unity game project for Android, and trying to integrate Google Play Games Services into my game. I got it to work at some point in testing mode. I now moved to production mode and it doesn't really work anymore.

At first:

- I Activated the Play Games Services in the Google Play Console.
- I created the OAuth consent screen in the Google Cloud Console in testing mode, and added my e-mail address to the testers list.
- I created a Credential in the Google Cloud Console with my debug key, and another one with my app signing key, found from the Google Play Console.
- I created two Credentials in the Google Play Console to link to the ones in the Cloud Console.
- I added my e-mail to the list of Play Games Services testers.
- I integrated the Play Games Services in my game
- I setup the Play Games Services with the resources IDs from the Play Console.
- And it worked (after a bit of trial and error).

Then, as I wanted to start moving to a Production environment, I submitted my OAuth screen consent for verification. The Google team asked me to change a few things, including removing my debug key from the credentials. They validated my request, and my OAuth screen consent moved to a Published status. Great.

Except at this point, the Play Games Services stopped working altogether. I couldn't sign in from my game anymore. After a while, I realised that I created a credential using my signing key, instead of my import key. So I created Credentials on the Cloud Console and the Play Console with my import key, and the Play Games Services started to work again.

But they seem to work only with accounts that already signed in while it was still in test mode.

I have another google account to test the game on another phone. When I try to start up the game on this other account, I can't connect to the Play Games Services. I even added this account's email address to the GPGS testers list, I made a Closed Testing release of the app, with this email added as a tester aswell. But I still can't connect to the GPGS, and it's a bit infuriating because I don't even receive a specific error code. I'm in the dark without any idea left of what I can do.

Thanks for any help you can bring!

Comment: If all else fails and you are unable to locate the stage in the authentication process where authentication fails, you could try backing up your files, deleting your project and resubmitting it.

Comment: That's what i'm sarting to consider :/

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails and you are unable to locate the stage in the authentication process where authentication fails, you could try backing up your files, deleting your project and resubmitting it.